# What is the reason for my "Variable Lengths Differ" error in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, reference, cross-validation

I am trying to use simple fitting and cross-validation in the following way:

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Auto)

Auto$cut.values = cut(displacement,2)
fit = glm(mpg~Auto$cut.values)
cv.glm(Auto, fit, K=10)$delta[1]
```

But I receive an error as:

> ```
> Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ Auto$cut.values, data = list( : variable 
> lengths differ (found for 'Auto$cut.values')
> ```

But if I try to slightly change the third line and run it then I get no error and obtain the result:

```
Auto$cut.values = cut(displacement,2)
fit = glm(mpg~cut.values, data = Auto)
cv.glm(Auto, fit, K=10)$delta[1]
```

As far as I know, `cut.values, data = Auto` is the same as `Auto$cut.values`.

What point I am missing here?

Comment: what about `mpg`? why you only care about `cut`? you should define what's mpg is referring to as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention it. But I used attach(Auto) before.

Comment: It is highly inadvisable to use `attach`. This is a common source of problems. You can use the temporary analog `with` and many functions have a data argument that will serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Imo. After all, I think I will follow your advice and not to use `attach` so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first `attach` your dataset there is no variable called `cut.values`. Therefore, you cannot refer to it later.

If you want to benefit from `attach` you need to  `attach(Auto)` after adding another variable to your dataset.

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Auto)

Auto$cut.values = cut(displacement,2)
attach(Auto)

fit = glm(mpg~cut.values)
cv.glm(Auto, fit, K=10)$delta[1]
```